# Accuracy.meas function in ROSE package of R

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

> I am using accuracy.meas function of ROSE package in R. I got the error **Response must have two levels**. So checked
>   both the parameter response and predicted1. But both are numeric. Is there some limitations to usability of accuracy.meas function.
>
> Note- The answer is wrong but it has nothing to do with error

```
accuracy.meas(test$Walc,predicted1,threshold = 0.5)
    Error in accuracy.meas(response=test$Walc,predicted= predicted1, threshold = 0.5) : 
      Response must have two levels.

>test$Walc
  [1] 1 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 3 3 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 4 2 1 1 1 1 4 4 4 5 1 1 1 1 3 1 2 3
 [42] 1 5 1 4 4 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 3 2 3 1 2 1 5 1 1 3 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 3 3 2 3 1 2
 [83] 2 2 1 1 3 1 1 1 2 3 3 1 1 3 1 2 1 5 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 3 1 2 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1
[124] 3 3 3 4 1 1 1 1 4 1 1 1 1 3 2 1 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 3 4 1 3 2 4 5
[165] 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 4 1 2 1 4 4 5 1 1 5 3 5 4 5 2 4 2 2 4 1 5 5 4 2 2 1 4 4 4 2 3 4
[206] 2 3 4 4 5 2 3 4 5 5 3 2 4 4 1 5 5 5 3 2 2 4 1 5 5 2 1 1 1 2 3 3 2 1 1 3 4 1 1 1 4
[247] 1 3 1 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 1 1 4 3 5 2 2 4 3 4 2 3
[288] 5 5 3 1 1 3 4 4 4 3 4 5 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 3 1 3 3 4 3
> predicted1
  [1] 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 4 4 1 1 1 1 3 2 2 3 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 5 3 3 2 2 2 1 1 2
 [42] 1 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 1 3 2 1 2 4 2 3 2 3 3 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 3 1 2 2 2
 [83] 2 2 1 1 3 2 2 1 1 3 3 1 2 2 2 3 1 3 3 3 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 1 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2
[124] 4 1 4 4 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 4 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 3 1 2 2 3 4
[165] 2 2 2 3 2 1 2 2 2 4 1 2 2 4 4 5 1 1 5 2 5 4 4 2 4 3 2 2 1 4 4 2 2 2 1 4 2 3 2 3 4
[206] 3 2 4 4 5 2 2 4 4 5 4 3 3 3 2 4 4 4 3 1 2 2 2 4 4 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 3 2
[247] 2 2 1 4 2 2 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 3 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 4 4 2 3 3 5 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
[288] 3 5 4 2 2 4 4 5 4 3 4 5 3 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 2 4 4 2 3
```

Comment: In the function you are using `predicted1` but you are showing us `predicted`.

Comment: Sorry ,Actually predicted and predicted1 was the same.Just Used round function to ensure all values are Integer.  Now corrected . Showing result of predicted1 .

Comment: @LyzandeR I have corrected the question. Can you please help me in solving my doubt